# Can ESP32 used for mobile game controller?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, esp32, keyboard, android

I have a term project: I need to develop a mobile game(Guitar Hero Like rhythm game) probably on Unity  and I need to develop a custom controller for this game that works on android device. There will be 3 buttons for notes and Bluetooth connections between android device and controller. My question is can I use ESP32 as a mobile game controller. If it's yes, which model that you suggest me?

Comment: Yes you can, Pick the most inexpensive one that supports Bluetooth, you only need 3 inputs.

Comment: Anything that supports BT/BLE could be used.